# How to use vue-smooth-dnd in Nuxt JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I apologize for my English, English is not my native language. Having problems using vue-smooth-dnd. Acted on the recommendations on GitHub. (https://github.com/kutlugsahin/vue-smooth-dnd)

I put the package in my Nuxt application, then created a file with the following code in the plugins.

```
import Vue from 'vue'; 
import VueSmooth from 'vue-smooth-dnd'; 
Vue.use(VueSmooth);
```

After which I registered the plugin inside nuxt.config and start using vue-smooth-dnd inside my component. I wrapped my code in 
`container`, and even each child in `draggable`. I add the `@drop="onDrop"` event to the `container` as shown in the documentation. But I do not get any result. What am I doing wrong? Please tell me how to use this library with Nuxt JS.

My nuxt.config.js - file

```js
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  loading: { color: '#fff' },
  css: [
  ],
  plugins: [     { src: '~/plugins/muuri.js', ssr: false}, { src: '~/plugins/smooth.js', ssr: false}

  ],
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss',
  ],
  modules: [
  ],
  build: {
    extend (config, ctx) {
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your `nuxt.config.js` file?

Comment: @AndrewVasilchuk added

Comment: Can you also provide the code of your component?